# Forcing the sum of the fixed effects to zero

Tags: r, regression

I am running a regression model with fixed effects (id). Rather than using the default, I would like to forcing the sum of the fixed effects to zero. In other words, the result of the last line of code below should be zero. I believe there is a way to use the contrasts argument to accomplish this, but I have not been able to find out exactly how. Any thoughts?

```
library(lfe)
m1 <- felm(y ~
x +
z | id, data = df)
fx_m1 <- getfe(m1)
sum(fx_m1$effects)
```

Answer (score 1):

What about `scale`ing the data? *Example:*

```
library(plm)
data("Produc", package="plm")
Produc[-(1:3)] <- scale(Produc[-(1:3)])
zz <- plm(gsp ~ pcap + pc + emp + unemp,
          data=Produc, index=c("state", "year"), model="within")
round(sum(fixef(zz)), 14)
# [1] 0
```

Comment: I should have been more clear: I would like to keep the estimates of x and z in my example and pcap, pc, emp and unemp the stable (i.e. they should not be adjusted). And the scaling also changes the distribution of the fixed effects which I am trying to prevent.